# How to make a hidden form with a file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have a dynamically generated table which is editable. On clicking any cell in the table I can change its text.

In one column there is an image displayed. When the user clicks on it I change the html for that column to `<input type='file'>` and trigger a click hence making the user choose a file to upload as the an icon.

In the last column of the table I have a commit button. If the user makes some changes and presses commit I have to pick up the whole row ( some text fields and one file field ) and add all the contents to a form including the file the user chose and send it to a python script to upload it to an s3 server.

My question is: How do I send this form?

I'm currently using script this but it is not working as it is only sending text as `request.Files` turns out empty at the python(django) script side.

```
function update(a) {
    try {
        var button = $(a);
        var row = $(button.parent());
        var rowcount = button.parent().parent().parent().children().index(button.parent().parent());
        var filerow = '';
        var formrow = new Array();
        var rowkey = new Array('Topic', 'TopicDescription');
        var cnt = 0;
        var form = $('#dyno_form');
        row.siblings().each(function () {
            if ($(this).find($('input:file')).length > 0) {
                $(this).find($('input:file')).appendTo($(form));
            } else if ($(this).find($('img')).length == 0) {
                formrow[cnt++] = '<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" name="' + rowkey[cnt - 1] + '"/>';
            }
        });
        $(form).append(formrow[0]);
        $(form).append(formrow[1]);
        $(form).submit();
    } catch (a) {
        alert(a);
    }
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
   <form id='dyno_form' action='' method="post" style="visibility:hidden">{% csrf_token %}</form>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: No it doesnt I should include that?

Comment: You have to if you want to upload a file.

Comment: Thanks man u should post that as an answer it works!

Comment: Ill add an edit and add my form faulty form declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to upload a file the `form` element needs to have the correct `enctype` attribute and the method must be `post`.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" ...
```

Otherwise only the values of your inputs will be uploaded.